# Pourquoi "des" mais pas " de l' " dans cette phrase? "Le livre X des Éléments d'Euclide"

Tags: grammaire, articles

J'ai lu dans Wikipédia :

> Le livre X **des Éléments** d'Euclide.

Pourquoi écrivent-ils **des Éléments** mais pas **de l'Éléments** ? Ce que je veux dire est que « Éléments », lui-même, est un nom propre (c'est le titre d'une collection de livres). Donc, *n'est-il pas exact* de dire :

> Le livre X **de l'Éléments** d'Euclide.

Ce serait génial si vous pouviez me donner une référence parce que je n'ai trouvé aucun résultat après une recherche sur Internet.

Comment: _Éléments_ n'est pas un nom propre, c'est un nom commun qui, ici est le titre d'un livre (d'où la majuscule). C'est exactement comme les _Essais_ de Montaigne: on dit bien les _Essais_ et non l'_Essais_ puisqu'il s'agit initialement d'un nom commun au pluriel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La question qui est posée est récurrente lorsque l'on parle des titres d’œuvres : où faut-il mettre une majuscule et que faire de l'article défini ? Dans le cas qui nous occupe ici, celui des Éléments, on écrira généralement :

> Euclide a écrit *Les Éléments* (ou *les Éléments*, selon les sources)
>
> Euclide a écrit les passionnants *Éléments*
>
> Dans ses *Éléments*, Euclide écrit que...
>
> On parlera aujourd'hui des *Éléments*, d'Euclide

L'Académie écrit :

> 7. Majuscules dans les titres d’œuvres
>
> Dans tous les titres d’œuvres, le premier terme au moins (ainsi bien sûr que les noms propres) prend la majuscule.
>
> **Si le titre commence par un article défini, le premier nom qui suit cet article ainsi que les adjectifs et adverbes le précédant éventuellement prennent la majuscule : Les Misérables, Les Très Riches Heures du duc de Berry, Le Petit Chaperon rouge, Le Vilain Petit Canard.
>   L’article défini en tête de l’œuvre ne prend la majuscule que s’il fait intrinsèquement partie du titre, et n’est pas contracté : l’Iliade ; Les Bienveillantes, mais un chapitre des Bienveillantes.**
>
> Si le titre ne débute pas par un article défini ou s’il consiste en une phrase conjuguée, seul le premier terme prend la majuscule (sauf s’il s’agit d’un adjectif : dans ce cas, le substantif suivant prend aussi la majuscule) : À la recherche du temps perdu, Terre des hommes, Un taxi mauve, Le train sifflera trois fois, Tristes Tropiques.
>
> Si le titre est double ou s’il met en opposition ou en parallèle deux termes, on applique les règles précédemment citées aux deux parties du titre, mais si la deuxième partie est introduite par un article défini, celui-ci perd sa majuscule : Le Rouge et le Noir, Vendredi ou les Limbes du Pacifique.

Sources : 
[Druide.com](https://www.druide.com/enquetes/titres-d%C5%93uvres-et-majuscules) ; [Université Lyon 2](http://sites.univ-lyon2.fr/lettres/zdoc-varia/MajusculesInBiblio.pdf) ; [Site de l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#47_strong-em-majuscules-em-strong) ; [Orthotypographie.fr](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html)

Comment: C'est fait pour la citation de l'Académie ; quant à l'italique, j'ai suivi en cela les recommandations du site orthotypographie, qui écrit : "Les titres d’œuvres sont doublement « balisés » : par l’italique (ou les guillemets) et par les capitales". Dans la question de Quelqu'un, le titre était en gras et en romain, mais c'est une mise en forme propre à Wikipédia ([lien de l'article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livre_X_des_%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_d%27Euclide)) pour le titre de ses articles (et non les titres d’œuvres).

Answer (score 0):

**Ce qui suit est mon avis personnel, n'est basé sur aucune règle que je connaisse, et entre sûrement en contradiction avec l'avis majoritaire de personnes plus qualifiées que moi.**

Edit : après qu'on m'a fait remarquer que le titre était « Les Éléments » et non « Éléments », je modifie en conséquence.

Je trouve ta question intéressante et, personnellement, mon ressenti est qu'on accorde pour l'unique raison que ça sonne mieux. Mais on peut se poser la question de la légitimité d'appliquer les règles de grammaire à un titre ou un nom propre.

Écrit-on :

> « Les Éléments » sont un livre très intéressant d'Euclide.

... ou plutôt :

> « Les Éléments » est un livre très intéressant d'Euclide.

... ou encore :

> Les « Éléments » sont un livre très intéressant d'Euclide.

... à moins que ce soit :

> Les « Éléments » est un livre très intéressant d'Euclide.

Pour moi il n'y a aucune raison d'appliquer une quelconque règle grammaticale sur un titre, puisqu'on le met justement entre guillemets pour préciser que c'est un titre et qu'il sort donc du contexte grammatical de la phrase.

Ce titre peut d'ailleurs être dans une langue étrangère, ou ça peut être un chiffre, ou un symbole.

Pour moi, la meilleure façon serait d'écrire :

> « Les Éléments » est un livre très intéressant d'Euclide.

On ne met pas d'article devant le titre, on ne sort pas l'article du titre, et on l'accorde au masculin singulier, peu importe que ce titre soit « Les Éléments », « Les trois petits cochons », « Pulp Fiction », ou autre :

> « Les Éléments » est très intéressant.
>
> « La Vie en rose » est très intéressant.
>
> « Dix petits nègres » est très intéressant.

Et donc pour ton cas, j'aurais écrit :

> Le livre X de « Les Éléments » d'Euclide.

Mais l'immense majorité des personnes sortent l'article du titre et accordent tout ça. Exemple sur Wikipédia :

> Les *Éléments* sont organisés comme suit [...]

On a donc « les » sorti du titre, « *Éléments* » en italique comme si c'était le titre de l'œuvre, et le verbe au pluriel. Chose qui me choque. Tout comme quand on dit « au Havre » et non « à Le Havre. »

Comment: On parle ici d'une série de livre nommée 'Les Éléments' et traduits 'The Elements' en anglais, et non pas 'Elements'. Il serait donc judiciable de se renseigner sur le sujet avant de donner une réponse. Voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_d%27Euclide . Merci

Comment: Merci, je modifie en conséquence, ce qui ne change pas grand chose à ma logique.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Le titre initial de ces ouvrages est en grec ancien et les titres français, anglais ou autres sont tous des traductions. Il ne s'agit donc pas du titre 'Les Éléments' qui est traduit 'The Elements'. D'ailleurs en fonction des nombreuses publications on peut retrouver les titres avec ou sans déterminant: 'Euclid's Elements' ou 'The Elements of Euclid', de même qu'en français on peut trouver 'Éléments' ou 'Les Éléments'.

Comment: En fait il existe deux écoles qui sont toutes les 2 bonnes, on peut dire le 'Le livre X de "Les Éléments" d'Euclide' mais on peut tout à fait dire Le livre X des Éléments d'Euclide. D'ailleurs le deuxièmes cas est bien plus commun et sonne mieux à l'oreille. On parlera donc par exemple Des Misérables de Victor Hugo et rarement de 'Les misérables'. Avant tout pour une question de sonorité.

Comment: Justement c'est tout le sujet de cette question, donc si tu as une source qui dit que les deux méthodes sont correctes, je suis preneur.

Answer (score -1):

it would be the same with every title when it's a plural.

the reason is that you must say "des" instead of "de les"

ex :"Il m'a dit du mal des Possédés" and not ""Il m'a dit du mal de Les Possédés".

(Les possédés being a book from Dostoiewski).

Answer (score -2):

Here "éléments" is a plural (end with the letter 's')

> un élément
>
> deux éléments

In french you can use

> de l'

for a singular but you have to use

> des

for a plural

Example :

> Le chant de l'oiseau (here "oiseau" is singular)
>
> Le chant des oiseaux (here "oiseaux" is plural)

Comment: Ce n'était pas sa question. Il sait cela mais étant donné que "Éléments" est le titre du livre, il se demande pourquoi l'accorder. Et je trouve cette question pertinente. Comme pourquoi dire "J'habite au Havre" alors que le nom de la ville est "Le Havre" et non "Havre". Pourquoi appliquer les règles de grammaire quand on parle de titres ou de noms propres ? Et j'ai l'impression que c'est plus pour que ça sonne bien, et non réellement parce que c'est correct.

Comment: Non en fait ici "Éléments" peut être consideré comme un nom propre étant donné qu'il est écrit en majuscule mais il s'agit aussi d'un nom commun, oui éléments ça existe. Pourquoi donc le conjugerait-on différemment sous prétexte qu'une majuscule y ai été ajoutée. Si un contre exemple peut me prouver le contraire, je l'accueille avec grand plaisir :) Pour vous (pour moi aussi d'ailleurs) cela semble 'sonner' mieux parce que vous êtes habitués à entendre la conjugaison de l'équivalent sous forme de nom commun avant tout.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner n'oublies pas de citer Simon dans ton commentaire, sinon il n'a pas de notification disant que tu as répondu... :)

Comment: @Random Effectivement, je n'y pense que rarement:(

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Le problème est assez spécifique aux titres d’œuvres (et recoupe dans certains cas celui des noms de ville, comme le souligne Simon) et je ne suis pas sûr que votre réponse satisfasse vraiment Quelqu'un.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Nous sommes justement dans un cas différent, la plupart des noms d'oeuvres pourrait effectivement être définit de la manière dont Simon le fait, par exemple avec la ville du Havre. Hors ici il s'agit déjà d'un mot pluriel qui de plus est avant tout un nom commun. C'est avant tout la raison pour laquelle nous pouvons le conjuguer comme un nom commun. Nous dirons par exemple "Le livre X des misérables" et non "Le livre X de 'Les misérables'" dans une grande majorité des cas.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Je ne crois pas que ce soit un cas spécifique : on écrira "la deuxième page des Éléments" comme on écrirait "la deuxième page du Prince, de Machiavel". La règle générale est que l'on contracte normalement l'article défini en tête de l’œuvre.